# How to remove all commas that are inside quotes (") with C# and regex

Tags: c#, regex

How to build a regex to remove all commas that are inside quotes(") using C# and then substitute them by @?

**Example**:

Initial string like this `= (value 1,value 2,"value3,value4,value5",value 6)`

Expected string like this `= (value 1,value 2,"value3@value4@value5", value 6)`

Comment: Do you mean to use `string.Replace` instead? -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You may also try `Regex.Replace(input, @"\B""\b[^""]+\b""\B", m => m.Value.Replace(",","@"))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
string input = "(value 1,value 2,\"value3,value4,value5\",value 6)";
var regex = new Regex("\\\"(.*?)\\\"");
var output = regex.Replace(input, m => m.Value.Replace(',','@'));
```

Comment: You were faster than me to write it, `"\".*?\""` is enough for the pattern though

Comment: Won't work for multilevel "quotes zones", for example: `"\"(value 1,value 2,\"value 3, value 4\",value 5,value 6)\""`

Comment: @PaviełKraskoŭski OP didn't mentioned such a thing ; in your sample I just see two quoted zones which are little odd (unbalanced parens) but nothing more

Comment: @Sehnsucht Ok, so your pattern is the best for this task.

Comment: @PaviełKraskoŭski maybe it's you that is right ; it's up to OP to tell

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you sir!!

Comment: `\\\"(.*?)\\\ ` did not work for me. However, @Sehnsucht's comment of using `"\".*?\""` instead, did work.

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "= (value 1,value 2,\"value3,value4,value5\",value 6)";
string pattern = "(?<=\".*),(?=.*\")";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "@");
```

Comment: Won't work if there are multiple "quoted zones" in the input, for example `"= (value 1,value 2,\"value3,value4,value5\",value 6,\"value7,value8\")"`

Answer (score 1):

Regex pattern referred below would work to identify data within double quotes even in multiple level
`Regex pattern: ([\"].*[\"])`

```
        List<string> input = new List<string>();
        input.Add("= (value 1,value 2,\"value3,value4,value5\",value 6)");
        input.Add("\"(value 1,value 2,\"value 3, value 4\",value 5,value 6)\"");
        var regex = new Regex("([\"].*[\"])");

        List<string> output = input.Select(data => regex.Replace(data, m=> m.Value.Replace(',','@'))).ToList();

        foreach(string dat in output)
            Console.WriteLine(dat);
```